# Android Align Spinner to right of Textview

Tags: java, android, textview, spinner

I would like to align my Spinner to right of a textview.. but the spinner is coming bottom of textview on the right side.. I am giving my code below and please help me what change I need to make for correction.

xml

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/age"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"

         android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"    
        android:entries="@array/age_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/age_prompt" />
```

Comment: Remove    `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2" `

Comment: Can you post your entire layout. So i can able to align it. Else i'll post my own one with your needs.

Comment: Actually I asked this question very long back... I got the solution also... Somebody replied it today...

Answer (score 1):

you can give `android:alignBaseLine`

Answer (score 1):

If you are in `LinearLayout`, you can use a `TableRow` tu put them horizontaly. Should look like:

```
<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tr"
  android:layout_width = "match_parent"
  android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
  android:orientation = "horizontal">

  <TextView 
    .......
    android:weight = "2"/>

  <Spinner
    .......
    android:weight = "1"/>
</TableRow>
```

If you are in `RelativeLayout` you can use `android:layout_toLeftOf ="@+id/textView2"`

The `TableRow` trick you can use it also in `RelativeLayout`.

Hope it helps!